# Diferença entre elemento.classe{} e elemento . classe{}

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu estava montando uma tela usando css e html, e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

a classe "x" é adicionada com um js, quando o usuario rola a barra lateral(se a posição for maior do que 0, a classe x é adicionada ao elemento).

aí no meu css eu precisava trocar a cor do fundo, entao coloquei:

```
elemento .x{
    codigo css...
}
```

e nao funcionou, porem quando eu coloquei assim:

```
elemento.x{
    codigo css...
}
```

Funcionou. Para quem nao viu diferença, está no espaço entre "elemento" e ".x".

OBS: tenho alguns codigos css em que eu coloco com espaço e funciona, porem estes nao sao adicionados com js.

Porque esse espaço faz diferneça em algumas situações e em outras não? Qual a diferença?

**Script que adiciona a classe:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        var header = document.querySelector("header");
        header.classList.toggle("x", window.scrollY > 0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tem a função js que adiciona a classe? Quando tem espaço estão percorrendo um caminho até o elemento, quando estão juntos significa o mesmo elemento. **Sem espaço** `<elemento class="x" />` **Com espaço** `<elemento> <p class="x"></p> </elemento>`

Comment: @PedroHenrique Tenho sim, vou deixar o js na pergunta. Obrigado pela sua resposta

Comment: simples, quando tem espaço ele procura pelo filho do elemento com a classe x, quando esta sem o espaço o css procura pelo elemento com a classe x

Comment: @SaMuK seu seletor no css é `header.x` ?

Comment: @PedroHenrique Sim, exatamente.

Comment: @SaMuK então está certo, quando você usar `header.x`, a estilização é aplicada no elemento `header` com a classe `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você utiliza em seu CSS a seguinte expressão, ou seja Seletor descendente.

```
.minhaClasse .subClasse {
    ...
}
```

Ocorre o seguinte: Elemento > Elemento, como a imagem abaixo descreve.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando expressado desta forma, classe combinada:

```
.mihaClasse.subClasse {
    ...
}
```

Entende-se que o elemento que possui `.minhaClasse` também possua `.subClasse`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito provavelmente a classe está sendo inserida no mesmo element por isso ocorreu de funcionar. Se você remover a sua classe que antecede a classe irá funcionar por que ficará independente da classe pai.

Caso de uso extra para melhor entendimento de quanto usar classe combinada.

```css
.textoGrande {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.textoGrande.textoCorAzul {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.textoGrande.textoNegrito {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="textoGrande">Meu texto grande</div>
<div class="textoGrande textoCorAzul">Meu texto grande e Azul</div>
<div class="textoGrande textoCorAzul textoNegrito">Meu texto grande, Azul e Negrito</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando tem espaço ele procura pelo filho do elemento com a classe x, quando esta sem o espaço o css procura pelo elemento com a classe x

Exemplo:

```css
div.x {
  color: red;
}

div .x {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  conteudo da div
  
  <p class="x">filho da div</p>
</div>
```